# Unit testing GraphQL's DataFetchingEnvironment issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, graphql, mockito

I have a query that takes  `classA` or `ClassB` parameter and gets information from the graph and returns to user based on `id` of `classA` or `classB`.

```java
public StudentSize get(final DataFetchingEnvironment dataFetchingEnvironment) {
  StudentSize ss = new StudentSize();
  final String classA = dataFetchingEnvironment.getArgument("classA");
  final String classB = dataFetchingEnvironment.getArgument("ClassB");
  if (classA is not empty) {
    ss = graphQLrepo.StudentSizefromClassA(classA);
  }else {
    ss = graphQLrepo.StudentSizefromClassB(classB);
  }
  return ss;
}
```

Now this working fine as it should. But when it comes to unit test cases it is failing. When I run `test1` it is passing
`test1` method:

```java
DataFetchingEnvironment  env = getDFenv();
String classAvalue = "58";
when(graphQLrepo.StudentSizefromClassA(classAvalue)).thenReturn(studentoutput);
StudentSize result = ssDataFetcher.get(env);
assertEquals(expectedResult, result);
```

but when I create another test `test2` method to cover else statement it is failing and is resulting in null rather than giving the expected output
test2 method:

```java
DataFetchingEnvironment env = getDFenv();
String classBvalue = "58";
when(graphQLrepo.StudentSizefromClassB(classBvalue)).thenReturn(studentoutput);
StudentSize result = ssDataFetcher.get(env);
assertEquals(expectedResult, result);
```

I checked and found out, in `test1` and `test2` both it is passing the same arguement for both `classA` value and `classB` value. So, it is passing the if statement and unable to return the desired output

```java
 private DataFetchingEnvironment getDFenv() {
        return new DataFetchingEnvironment() {
...
   @Override
   public <T> T getArgument(String s) {
        return (T) "58";

            }
   "Everything else inside this is returning null"

...
```

I do not know where I went wrong and I'm trying to figure out how to pass only the required value in the test or a way to fail the condition check in if statement during test run. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you mocking DataFetchingEnvironment to test this?